# Как правильно отследить изменение размера div-элемента компонента React JS?

Tags: react-hook

Очень нужна помощь в понимании, как отслеживать в функциональном компоненте, с учетом всех этапов жизненного цикла, размеры некоторых блоков компонента и уже от этого выстраивать перерисовку компонента.

Есть сетка grid компонента React и мне нужно получать размер одного из элементов этой сетки при изменении его размера. Я использую функциональный тип компонентов, но все никак не могу корректно считать эти значения при изменении окна. Использую useEffect для начального считывания значения элемента - все выходит, но не соображу как правильно отлавливать дальнейшее изменение этого элемента. Вот код компонента:

```js
import './css/mainbanner.css';
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { REACT_APP_API_URL } from '../../utils/constants';

const MainBanner = () => {
    const sliderLine = useRef();
    const sliderWrapper = useRef();
    const mb = {
        'mb': {
            list: [
                {
                    title: 'Слайд 1',
                    descr: 'Описание.',
                    btn_title: 'Подробнее',
                    image: 'b-01.jpg',
                    link: '/',
                    style: 1
                },
                {
                    title: 'Слайд 2',
                    descr: 'Описание … подходящий под новые размеры.',
                    btn_title: 'Смотреть сейчас',
                    image: 'b-02.jpg',
                    link: '/',
                    style: 1
                },
            ]
        }
    }

    const resizeSlider = () => {
        console.log(sliderWrapper.current.offsetWidth);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (sliderWrapper.current) resizeSlider();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="banner-wrapper">
            <div className="mb" ref={sliderWrapper}>
                <div className="sliderline" ref={sliderLine}>
                    <div className="slide" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${REACT_APP_API_URL}banners/b-01.jpg` }}>
                        Hello world
                    </div>
                    <div className="slide" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${REACT_APP_API_URL}banners/b-02.jpg` }}>
                        Hello world
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="b1"></div>
            <div className="b2"></div>
            <div className="b3"></div>
            <div className="b4"></div>
        </div>
    );
};
export default MainBanner;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно при изменении размера окна обновлять состояние компонента и при рендере использовать полученные данные примерно так:

```js
// import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [size, setSize] = React.useState({});
  const ref = React.useRef();

  const resizeHandler = () => {
    const { clientHeight, clientWidth } = ref.current || {};
    setSize({ clientHeight, clientWidth });
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
    resizeHandler();
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Please resize window ... </h3>
      <div
        ref={ref}
        style={{ border: "1px solid red", margin: "2rem", height: "70vh" }}
      >
        <div>
          clientHeight: {size.clientHeight}, clientWidth:{size.clientWidth}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Константин, спасибо! Все мне теперь понятно. Вы написали ответ как в useEffect правильно добавить и убрать листенер. Отлично!

Comment: Отлично, пожалуйста отметьте ответ как правильный если всё ок.

Answer (score 0):

Закину в копилку решений:

```
const [windowWidth, setWindowWidth] = React.useState(window.screen.width);

React.useEffect(() => {
    window.onresize = () => {setWindowWidth(window.screen.width)};
    // Ваш код
    return () => {window.onresize = false};
}, [windowWidth]);
```